Why is the question about women rejecting unsuitable man about individual person?
The question How does a woman reject an unsuitable man? was closed as off-topic for the reason of asking about a behavior of individual person. However, I fail to see how this reason stands. The symptoms the OP lists are not enough to draw any individual. It goes along with General strategies for converting self-help into a useful general question for this site.
Can you elucidate me why it was closed? How should it be fixed?
For comparison, in Health Stack Exchange - a site which also accept non-self help questions and answers with citations only, such questions are perfectly normal. For example:

What are these lines in teeth?
The following tooth cracks are noticeable when a torch is shining on them (without the torch, they aren't visible).  Are they serious?  How viable are the teeth, and might they need to be replaced with false teeth in the near future?  There is no pain experienced, but they seem to look quite bad:



Following question: https://cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2233/12937

Although it is not phrased as a self-help question, the question is anecdotal and does ask about diagnosis, which we do not do. That is the reason the self-help close vote reason exists. As also argued by Artem a while back:

[...] self-help questions are inherently anecdotal questions. They are too specific to the person asking, and often non-scientific in nature. We are not a general health, productivity, or well-being site; we are a site about science.

If the question is about some sort of hypothetical situation, than again it is considered as something you should not ask (from "don't ask")

To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
[...]

you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”

[...]

Finally, we don't know where the symptoms came from. They may be subjected to the OP's own interpretation. When the assumptions are unclear or appear to lack any backing, the question may be closed as primarily opinion based.

I don't see how it's anecdotal. The OP lists some symptoms, and what that is. Maybe a slight edit will help?

In my opinion, the question sketches a particular situation and asks for a diagnosis. To me that comes across as an anecdotal question, possible a covered up self-help question, or otherwise a random hypothetical situation (which is also a reason for questions to be closed). I'll describe that in the post

I know it's a different site, but in [health.Stack Exchange], questions listing symptoms and asking for diagnosis are perfectly fine. I don't see how this site should be different. An example: What are these lines in teeth?

I think that it all boils down to my first point, a lack in expertise. Perhaps if you could propose a format to ensure high quality questions, people could agree to keep similar question open

Would retitling it as "What makes a personality of rapid anger outburst?" help?

@Ooker it is not about the title per se. I did like your edits (but am unsure whether the question will be reopened). What I meant by "suggesting a format" was to post an answer in this question in which you outline how a similar question should look like to make it on-topic (i.e. not self-help or opinion based): What kind of research does a question require, how should the symptoms be identified etc., and also explain how these questions may be of (scientific) value here. If people like the proposal, similar question may stay open in the future.

Well, I think the question General strategies for converting self-help into a useful general question for this site covers it pretty well.
